# How to add swagger-ui to jersey jaxrs web application?

Tags: web-applications, jersey, jax-rs, swagger-ui, web.xml

I managed to add swagger core to my web app but I could not find a solution to add swagger-ui to my jersey jax-rs web application.

Except here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/blob/2.0/java/java-jersey2-webxml/pom.xml

There are a plethora of spring boot examples but not for jersey jax-rs with web.xml.

However, in some places, I saw instructions, to check out the 'dist' directory of the swagger-UI source code from Github and then add everything to the 'webapp' directory and then to change the URL in the index.html.

I tried using the maven com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin and maven-resources-plugin and manually adding index.html but did not work for me.

Is there any other way I could automate this? That is to automatically add swagger-ui to jersey jax-rs web application?

In see that maven repository has;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.25.4</version>
</dependency>
```

but could not find any usage of it.

Appreciate any redirection to a source that I could refer to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use glassfish mvc to create new Viewable() and supply all files in ur static directory.